# Code gives right number first time its compiled, second time, gives random number

Tags: c

So, I have a program to calculate the bisection, it works the first time I compile it, but the next time I compile, it gives me a different number, not the right one. I compile the program with the terminal, gcc  -o exec.

I tried changing everything that could be changed, but I didn't find my mistake.

```c
float Bissecao (float a, float b){

    //Recebe o valor do PontoMedio entre A e B
    float x;

    //Variaveis para receber o valor da funcao ao substituir por a e b e x
    float fxa, fxb, fx,  absoluto;

    //Ponto Medio e Calculos
    x = (a + b) / 2;    

    //APENAS PARA EXEMPLO
    fx = pow(x, 3) - 9*x + 5;
    fxa = pow(a, 3) - 9*a + 5;
    fxb = pow(b, 3) - 9*b + 5;


    while (absoluto > 0.01){
        fxa = pow(a, 3) - 9*a + 5;
        fxb = pow(b, 3) - 9*b + 5;

        if ((fxa > 0 && fx > 0 ) || (fxa < 0 && fx < 0)){
            a = x;  
            x = (b + x) / 2;
        }else if ((fxb < 0 && fx < 0) || (fxb > 0 && fx > 0)){
            b = x;
            x = (a + x) / 2;
        }
        //fx = 4*sin(x) - pow(2.718281828459045235360287, x);
        fx = pow(x, 3) - 9 * x + 5;
        absoluto = fabs(fx);
    }
    printf("A raiz da equacao e %.4f\n", x);

    return fx;
}
```

I expect to get the right number when I execute it.

Comment: For future reference, please provide a [mcve] in your question. You've shown us a function, but you haven't shown us the code that calls it (the `main` function). We should be able to copy-and-paste the code from your question and run it ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable 'absoluto' is uninitialized.

Changing the test of the loop to :

```
while (fabs(fx) > .01f)
{
     /* ... */
}
```

Should fix the issue.